# Infinitive after Preposition

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

As I know, gerunds must be used after prepositions but I heard the sentences below in a movie. Is it possible to use such constructions ?

> 1-"He is waiting for me to call him" I thought it must be "He is
>   waiting for my calling him"
>
> 2-"I am not asking for her to be changed" I thought it must be "I am
>   not asking for her being changed"

Comment: "As I know, gerunds must be used after prepositions" - I'm not sure where you heard this, but it's not correct, as a general rule.  Both of the examples you quote are fine as they are, and sound better than the version with the gerund.

Comment: "For" is not a preposition in the first example of each pair: it's a clause subordinator - a special marker for verb phrases of infinitival clauses. In the second example in each pair "for" is a preposition, but grammatically the result is marginal at best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Is the part "for me to call him" purpose of infinitive ? also is there a rule that help me learn after which prepositions I can use infinitives like in the example 2 ?

Comment: No, "for me to call him" is not a purpose adjunct, but a catenative complement. It identifies the event he was waiting for. With infinitivals that have a subject, as in your example, you can only use the subordinator "for".